# Can we use the new BottomNavigationBar as a temporary snackbar?

Tags: cosmicmind

I know the Snackbar is "upcoming," but in the mean time, is it safe to use BottomNavigationBar?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the BottomNavigationBar, now BottomTabBar, as a Snackbar because it doesn't offer the proper layout you would be looking for. I added an example project in development -> Programmatic called `ControlView` that will show you how to use the ControlView class to create a Snackbar. Btw, a ControlView is a parent class for the SearchBar and Toolbar, and will be the basis of what the Snackbar will be created from. Here is the UIViewController code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
/// Reference for ControlView.
private var controlView: ControlView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    prepareView()
    prepareControlView()
}

/// General preparation statements.
private func prepareView() {
    view.backgroundColor = MaterialColor.white
}

/// Prepares the controlView
private func prepareControlView() {
    controlView = ControlView(frame: CGRectMake(0, view.bounds.height - 56, view.bounds.width, 56))

    // Undo button.
    let undoButton: FlatButton = FlatButton()
    undoButton.pulseScale = false
    undoButton.pulseColor = MaterialColor.white
    undoButton.setTitle("UNDO", forState: .Normal)
    undoButton.setTitleColor(MaterialColor.teal.accent1, forState: .Normal)

    let label: UILabel = UILabel()
    label.text = "Archived"
    label.textColor = MaterialColor.white

    controlView.backgroundColor = MaterialColor.grey.darken4
    controlView.contentView.addSubview(label)
    controlView.rightControls = [undoButton]
    controlView.contentInsetPreset = .WideRectangle3

    view.addSubview(controlView)
    controlView.contentView.grid.views = [label]
}
}
```